# Origin of 'to call out', meaning to decry

Tags: etymology, american-english

[This question](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/431483/what-is-the-meaning-of-call-out-in-this-sentence) discusses the use of **"call out"**, meaning to publicly denounce or decry a person or a behaviour. One of the answers to that question gives an earliest known use of the expression from 1981.

I wonder how this expression arose? Is it an abbreviation or generalisation of an expression from a particular field of activity? For example, a teacher 'calling out' an unruly child from behind their desk, or whatever?

***[EDIT]***

Thanks for the suggestions. Obviously, 'call' is a very basic/common verb, and there are loads of idioms involving it. There are various well-established uses of "call out" as well: one cowboy 'calling out' another for a duel; a tennis umpire calling "out"; "call out the guards" to quell a rebellion; and so on.

What I specifically want to know is which, if any, of the earlier senses of "call out" led to the modern usages - *"call out [bad behaviour X]"* and/or *"call [person X] out on her [bad behaviour Y]"*. (I take it as read that the former usage is a contraction of the latter).

Example: ***"Always call out everyday sexism!"***

Evidence that the usage arose 'spontaneously', without reference to any other sense of the phrase, would also be acceptable as an answer, of course.

Comment: I guess I've always associated it with old US "western" movies (and likely some swashbucklers as well).  One person stands outside of a bar and *calls out* his nemesis, so they can have a showdown.

Comment: It should be noted that what is likely a more recent meaning means calling out the the name of someone in a group for some special recognition.  Not quite a "shout out", but close.

Comment: Yes, the 'westerns' idea makes sense as an origin... although the current usage in the media makes me think more of fishwives than gunslingers.

Comment: Also note that there are many other common collocations of "call out".  The obvious one is "calling out" to another person at a distance.  And there's "call out" the militia.  The noun form of "call out" may be used for some sort of announcement.  "Call out" is apparently used to mean some sort of "on call" part-time employment.

Comment: Consider also **to single out** and perhaps even the probably more recent **to** (give) **a shout out to**

Comment: I suspect that's too new and rare a use to be recognised as anything but odd. Possibly someone's personal style but by no means idiomatic… yet.

Comment: there are theological uses of "to call out" as well as finding it  in old tomes. pray tell is this the path to the bounty? lol

Comment: @lbf , what are the specifically theological uses? The path to the bounty is: a)  to give me a plausible path from older usage(s) to the usage described in the question, backed up with sources (literary, lexicographical, ngrams, whatever); or, b) to show, with suitable research, that it's imponderable; or, c) to give sufficient evidence to show that the usage arose 'spontaneously', for example as part of a pattern of usage change in a particular sub-culture/locale.

Comment: @ArchContrarian  I shall complete my research today.

Comment: @ArchContrarian posting my answer soon ... if i am way off pls let we kn0w so this  humble member can quickly delete and exit gracefully lol!

Comment: I always think of professional wrestling, where one wrestler stands in the ring, microphone in hand calling, for his nemesis to come out of the locker room and fight him. But they may have gotten that idea from westerns, as someone else pointed out.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The *OED* includes the 1981 date as the earliest attestation of this specific sense of **call out**, but it also cross-references **call on** which was used earlier in a similar sense.  The earliest attestation of this use is from **1944**.

> You could (and should) promptly **‘call’ him on it** and ask him to prove it.

- **1944**  - *Cedar Rapids* (Iowa) *Tribune* 9 Nov. 3/2

This sense of "call on" is cross-referenced to another sense of **call** pertaining to gambling.

> (c) *trans. fig.* and in figurative contexts. To accept (a person's) challenge or offer; to challenge (a person) to fulfil a declared intention. Also with the challenge or intention as object. Cf. **to call one's (or the) bluff at bluff n.2 3a .**

This series of cross-references suggests to me that there is likely a connection between the earlier gambling expression "call," meaning to match someone's bet in a game of cards, essentially "challenging" their hand, and the modern expression "call out" meaning to challenge someone publicly.  The gambling connection doesn't completely explain the "out," which I would attribute to the tendency for this expression to mean that someone is being "exposed" or challenged *publicly*.

Answer (score 4):

**To call out** seems to be a hybridization of two historically related idioms: **To call to account** and **To call out**.

According to [*English Idioms*](https://archive.org/stream/englishidioms00dixouoft#page/38/mode/2up), by James Main Dixon, ca 1902, pp39-40 :

> **To call to account** - to censure; to demand an explanation from
>
> **To call out** - to challenge to fight a duel

There is (often enough) an aggressive quality to the *habit* of calling people out, making it fairly obvious how the two idioms may have naturally merged to become the one that was historically the most terrifying.

Answer (score 1):

The only certain way to get a precise and certain answer to this question is probably doing a lot of textual studies using bots and older books, but my impression would be that there is little difference between previous uses of "call out" and the current-day use of "call out". It would not seem far fetched to see the evolution of "calling someone out" that is, calling attention to others about someone's behavior or calling attention to that person about his/her behavior.